# How to handle files with spaces in batch scripts?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am creating a batch file to execute few programs but having trouble with `pro gra mme.exe`. The script gets stuck on

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dir 1\Main"
start "pro gra mme.exe"
```

While executing I am getting prompt with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dir 1\Main>`.
What could be the problem? I am adding using double quotes in `start "pro gra mme.exe"` to counter the spaces.

Comment: If the first parameter to `start` is enclosed in double-quotes, it is taken as a title. So you need to supply a dummy parameter: `start "" "pro gra mme.exe"`.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @AFH start takes the **first** argument in double quotes as the title independent from it's position it well may be the last.

Comment: @LotPings - I've never seen that: the help information (`start /?`) says that the title is an optional quoted first parameter. I just tested it on Win10 and it follows the specification: `start cmd "Title"` ignores "Title".

Comment: @AFH I just tested with my actual Win 10 and there seem to be a new behaviour  `start /D "%USERPROFILE%" "my title" cmd` works now - and I'm pretty shure for a long time this did **not** work. So now it depends on the Windows version used

Comment: @LotPings - The `/D` option takes one argument, so `"my title"` is still the first _positional_ parameter. According to `start /?` any title should come before the options, but maybe they've relaxed it to allow options to precede; they obviously can't come after the command, where any options will be for the command.

Comment: @AFH yes but this `taking` didn't work formerly.

Comment: @LotPings - That's what I implied by "maybe they've relaxed it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I am adding using double quotes in `start "pro gra mme.exe"` to counter the spaces

Please read the help for `start`.

```
Syntax

  START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

In your case `"pro gra mme.exe"` is being interpreted by the `cmd` shell as the *title*.

You can use the following command instead:

```
start "" "pro gra mme.exe"
```

Note:

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or
>   just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but
>   depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is
>   omitted.

Source - [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: Once in a while there's a tool that amuses me with its odd design.