# Why cannot I specify a full path to executable to start command in cmd?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I can launch exe by specifying its path:
`c:\> "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"` , now trying doing the same with `start`:

```
c:\> start /separate  "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

will launch only another instance of `cmd.exe`, but not visual studio. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Windows 64-bit? Help for the START command says that /SEPARATE and /SHARED are not supported on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: 64. But it still works, why then so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle files with spaces in batch scripts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1218798/how-to-handle-files-with-spaces-in-batch-scripts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the first argument to `start` is quoted, it is interpreted as the title of the window. So you need:

```
start /separate "" "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

As Steve Rindsberg's comment indicates, I don't think you meant `/separate`. It will likely be ignored on modern platforms.